# How can I create multiple unique instances of one object and add them to a list with python and pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

Here is the code for the Train class:

```
class Train(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
def __init__(self):
    pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self) #call Sprite initializer
    self.image, self.rect = load_image('train.bmp', -1)
    ...
```

And here is where I create the individual train instances, within the main loop:

```
trains = pygame.sprite.Group()
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event ...:
            train = Train()
            train.add(trains)
```

How can I make each instance of train unique?

Comment: I think the last line should be `trains.add(train)`.

Comment: also the Sprite initializer ought to be called as `super(Train,self).__init__()`  In what way are the trains not currently unique?

Comment: Define "unique". (Actually, that might also be the solution for your actual question - override `__eq__` and `__hash__` and you got a definition of equality.)

Comment: Each train is stored inside of the group as "train." I guess my problem is accessing each individual train during the game loop. What if i want to change a variable of only one of the trains within the group?

Answer (score 1):

Your code creates a variable train, but never uses train**s**. I renamed the variable to train_list to make it clearer.

```
train_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
done = False # any code can toggle this , to request a nice quit. Ie ESC

while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event ...:
            train = Train()
            train_list.add(train)
```

Read [docs: pygame.sprite.Group](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group)
And [piman's sprite pygame tutorial](http://www.sacredchao.net/~piman/writing/sprite-tutorial.shtml)

> > What if I want to change a variable of one of the trains?

```
# modify a variable on one train
train_list[2].gas = 500

# kill train when out of gas
for cur in train_list:
    # this will call Sprite.kill , removing that one train from the group.
    if cur.gas <= 0:
        cur.kill()
```

> > How do I update all trains?

You can define Train.update, to use gas, since [Sprite.update](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#Sprite.update) is called by SpriteGroup.update

```
Train(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Train, self).__init__()
        self.gas = 100
    def update(self)
        self.gas -= 1 # or you can use a variable from the caller
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if you need to identify a train you could add a ID to every single one of them something like this:

```
class Train(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, ID = None):
        # train goes here, maybe even a counter that changes "ID" to something if not user-defined.
```

and then loop them over:

```
for train in trains:
    if ID == "whatever you like":
        #Do something
```

! Pseudo code !